# Do empty functions get optimized away in Rust?

Tags: optimization, rust

I want to put some performance impacting function calls behind a feature gate in my code. If the feature isn't enabled, I was thinking of just having an empty implementation of that function implemented instead. That way, hopefully, the Rust complier can completely remove that from the function.

Something like this:

```
// Included if feature is enabled
fn foo() {
    // ...
}

// Included if the feature is disabled
fn foo() {}

// Performance critical code
for i in 1..1000000000 {
    // ...
    foo();
}
```

Would the call to foo() get optimized away if it is empty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try it in the amazing [*Compiler Explorer*](https://godbolt.org/g/9oHgry) :)

The result assembly for your example is:

```
example::main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     eax, 1
.LBB0_1:
    xor     ecx, ecx
    cmp     eax, 1000000000
    setl    cl
    add     ecx, eax
    cmp     eax, 1000000000
    mov     eax, ecx
    jl      .LBB0_1
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

As you can see there is no `call` instruction and `foo()` isn't called at all. However, you might wonder why the loop isn't removed, as it doesn't have an effect on the outside world. I can just assume that sometimes those loops are in fact used to waste time in some sense. If you decrease the counter to `100`, the loop is completely removed.

Anyway: **Yes**, the optimizer will remove empty functions!

Comment: I was wondering about why the loop itself isn't removed, thanks for mentioning it; maybe someone can explain this behavior.

Comment: This behavior with the loop is really weird (especially the 100 threshold). When using Clang those loops are fully removed, so I would assume LLVM is capable to do it with Rust too, yet I can't seem to trigger it :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. The loop is optimized away with `let mut i = 1_000_000_000; while i > 0 {foo(); i -= 1;}`

Comment: @ArtemGr: This smells like a bug :x

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my example, you could imagine that the loop would have other stuff in it as well (hence the `// ...`) so having the loop also removed is less important to me. Good explanation though!

Comment: I believe that's just an issue with Compiler Explorer not doing all optimizations. On my computer, I get exactly the same asm for the example as for `fn main() {}`.

Comment: You could pass `-C remark=all` to see optimization remarks. The loop failed to optimize because "could not determine number of loop iterations" @paholg @MatthieuM

Comment: Just filed an issue at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41097 about the loop optimization for record.

Answer (score 1):

According to my check with release mode on current stable Rust, the following code:

```
fn foo() {}


fn main() {
    for _ in 1..1000000000 {
        foo();
    }

    println!(); // a side effect so that the whole program is not optimized away
}
```

Compiles to the same assembly as if the loop was empty:

```
for _ in 1..1000000000 {}
```